# Appending no of lists to an existing excel file starting from a specific cells with Python, Openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, excel, list, openpyxl

I'm getting no of list's in `my_list` variable trough iterating a `dictionary -> employee_data`, its not a list of list its coming trough in `for loop` one by one, look into code below...

```
print(my_list)

    ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
    ['B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'B']
    ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']
    ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
    ['D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D']
```

1. I just want to add those `list's` item in `excel` from cell between `ws['C3':'H' + str(ws.max_row)]` like this is it possible in loop ?

[image]

and my code is

```
for key,day_value in employee_data.items():
        attendance_array = []
        for val_key, get_value in day_value.items():
            attendance_array.append(get_value)
        my_list = attendance_array[n:]
        print(my_list)

        for rw in ws['C3':'H' + str(ws.max_row)]:
            for cell, val in zip(rw, my_list):
                cell.value = val
```

Comment: I think the nested loops, if real, could be causing problems. I no longer debug code which uses parametric range calculation instead of `ws.iter_rows()`

Comment: Hello @CharlieClark please help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code reads 1 list from employee_data dictionary so presumably ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] then applies this one list to all 5 rows since your create a range from C3 to H7 then you get the next list, ['B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'B'] and do the same thing and so on for the rest of the lists. Not sure why your range needs to extend to column H since the last column is G but you need to set the range the first loop as C3:G3 i.e. row 3 only then on next loop set range to C4:G4, then next loop C5:G5 etc
Example

```
...
row = 3
for key, day_value in employee_data.items():
    attendance_array = []
    for val_key, get_value in day_value.items():
        attendance_array.append(get_value)
    my_list = attendance_array[n:]
    print(my_list)

    for rw in ws[f'C{row}:G{row}']:
        for cell, val in zip(rw, my_list):
            cell.value = val
    row += 1
```